# Query to Stored Procedure in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services

I am getting data from a table and I am writing off to the report through a stored procedure. In the reporting part it has to show the results by users defined date.

E.g:

```
Today - should show today's results only
Yesterday - should show Yesterday's results only
```

How should I declare the values in a stored procedure and how can I implement in ssrs reporting part?

My `CreateDate` column keeps changing has the table (`FailedJobsInfo`) gets updated.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[FailedJobsInfo] 
    @StartDate DATETIME
AS
    SELECT 
      [SQLServer]
      ,[JobName]
      ,[StepName]
      ,[FailureMessage]
      ,[RunDateTime]
      ,[RunDuration]
      ,[CreateDate]
    FROM 
      [dbo].[FailedJobsInfo]
    WHERE  
      CONVERT(varchar(20), CreateDate, 101) = CONVERT(varchar(20), GETDATE(), 101)
```

Comment: WHERE CONVERT(varchar(20),CreateDate, 101) >= DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) in sql server or in SSRS may be this works https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RTAbpIlKahU

Comment: How about this? WHERE CAST(CreateDate AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)

Answer (score 0):

Starting from your SSRS Report.

1) Create a Parameter with Labels and Values as below

```
 Label        Value
 Today          0
Yesterday       1
```

2) Make your Procedure to accept an `INT` Parameter, If user selects `Today` it will pass zero `0` to stored procedure, if user selects `Yesterday` it will pass procedure `1` to procedure and this Integer value will be subtracted from your getdate() value avoiding time part. you will need to do as follow :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[FailedJobsInfo] 
    @StartPeriod INT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
      [SQLServer]
      ,[JobName]
      ,[StepName]
      ,[FailureMessage]
      ,[RunDateTime]
      ,[RunDuration]
      ,[CreateDate]
    FROM 
      [dbo].[FailedJobsInfo]
    WHERE  
      CAST(CreateDate AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) - @StartPeriod  --<-- 
END
```